# How do I get text color to contrast its container?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

With Quasar, I'm trying to put `q-breadcrumb-el` inside a `q-toolbar`.
However, the breadcrumb text is invisible, because it's the same color as the background of the toolbar (the theme primary color).
Quasar components intended for use in the toolbar (e.g `q-toolbar-title`) render text in a color that contrasts correctly.
I can hard-code the color in my template, but that will fail if the theme primary color is changed to a light color.

1. Is there a common idiom to say something like, "contrasting with background color" or "same color as text in xxx element"  in Quasar (or Vue, or vanilla CSS)?  (I.e, something that all the cool kids just know?)
2. How can I determine how `q-toolbar-title` does it?

```html
<q-toolbar>
  <q-toolbar-title>Wiki Page</q-toolbar-title>  <!-- <== white text on primary color background -->
  <q-breadcrumbs>
    <q-breadcrumbs-el
      v-for="section in sections"
      :key="section.label"
      :label="section.label"
      :to="section.path"
      class="text-white"    <!-- <== works, but is fragile -->
    ></q-breadcrumbs-el>
  </q-breadcrumbs>
</q-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If I get want you mean.

- Add a CSS text-stroke property the color should be black or white only.
  So as to differentiate the text color from the toolbar color.

```
<q-toolbar>
  <q-toolbar-title>Wiki Page</q-toolbar-title>  <!-- <== white text on primary color background -->
  <q-breadcrumbs style="font-size: 20px;-webkit-text-stroke: 0.4px black;">
    <q-breadcrumbs-el
      v-for="section in sections"
      :key="section.label"
      :label="section.label"
      :to="section.path"
      class="text-white"    <!-- <== works, but is fragile -->
    ></q-breadcrumbs-el>
  </q-breadcrumbs>
</q-toolbar>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I was hoping there'd be a way to avoid declaring an explicit color for text-stroke. I'd like something that means 'black when background is white, but white when background is black', or, more generally, 'a whole bunch darker when the background is light and a whole bunch lighter when the background is dark'.